# Is it needed to close the <script> tag when it's used for embedding an external script file?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

In old times we used to embed external JavaScript this way:

```
<script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML5 came to save our eyes and fingers, so the construct became shorter:

```
<script src=external.js></script>
```

Not a big deal, I'm just curious if we can leave away the enclosing `</script>`?

Like this:

```
/* This code may fail */

<script src=external.js/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: Why do you ask?  Do browsers support this now?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski, well, Chrome does not, and probably won't. That's enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `<script>` tag requires separate opening and closing tags, although you may get away with using a self-closing tag if the page's `Content-type` is set to `application/xhtml+xml`.

See the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

Comment: required in html5 as well

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there are self-closing tags (like `<hr>` and `<br>`) and non self-closing tags, `<script>` being one of them

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in [W3C HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) and [W3C HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script-tags):

> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

Even if some browsers allow end tag absence, your code can break in every moment, because it's not valid.

So answer: No